# Android: GetText from TextView Doesn't Do Anything?

Tags: android, textview

I have the code below

```
final TextView bT = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.b_t);
Log.e(LOG_TAG, bT.getText().toString());
if (bT.getText() == null) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "NULL");
} else if (bT.getText() == null) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "NULL");
}
```

I'm trying to make a conditional where if the text for bT isn't set yet, I set it.

This has the minor problem of not doing anything at all - even the log tags don't show up.

I know that I have the right view, because I can call setText() just fine, and I know that the code actually reaches this point, because

Log.e(LOG_TAG, LOG_TAG)

will work just fine.

I just have no idea how to set the conditional here.

Comment: `getText()` won't return null. If the `TextView` is empty, it'll return an empty `Editable`. Also, both of those `if`s are exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
EditText bT = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b_t);
String strGetText= bT.getText().toString();
if (strGetText.trim().equals("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "NULL");
    return;
}
```

or

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(strGetText)) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "NULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "NULL");
    return;
}
```

I hope it can help your problem!

Answer (score 2):

Use `TextUtils` to check whether the TextView is empty

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(bT.getText().toString())) {
     Log.e(LOG_TAG, "NULL");
}else{
     // do whatever you want
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution which differentiates getText into a variable `strGetText` and ensuring that it should not be an empty.

```
final TextView bT = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.b_t);
String strGetText= bT.getText().toString()
Log.e(LOG_TAG, bT.getText().toString());

if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(strGetText)) {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "It's not null");
} else {
    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "It's null");
}
```